# How to make a Seaborn heatmap saved version similar to the one displayed with Matplotlib show?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a Seaborn's heatmap that has small cells. When I display it using Matplotlib show function it nicely merge contigous cells, but when I save it to a png file it shows all cells separately.

This is what I get using Matplotlib's show function:

[image]

And this is what I get when I save it to a file:
[image]

How can I get a similar merge effect saving the file?

Comment: My first check would be outputting a svg or pdf (or anything not rasterized) to see if rasterization is the culprit here. Next thing would be playing with dpi-param. And then, i would do the annoying research on how to tune it otherwise.

Comment: Hi @sascha, I've just tried your suggestion. By lowering dpi value (150 dpi) alliviates the problem, but I would really like my image at 300 dpi. Also, it would be really great to have a raster version of it.

Comment: Lowering? Interesting! Sadly i can't offer any more insight but i'm sure someone els will. I have to admit, that i'm not a huge fan of rasterized images (if those will be put to latex and co. later; and i always cry if some colleague want's something to put into MS Word).

Comment: It makes sense that lowering the resolution merges the cells and that high resolution shows that they are not actually merged

Comment: Yes, but i also thought, insanely high dpi-values should approximate the original at some point (although display-dpi might play a role and original = internal & displayed-version might differ too).

Comment: The image on screen is probably produced with 100 dpi (when run as script) or 72 or 80 dpi in a notebook. If the resolution is different when saving the image (i.e. 300 dpi) you would have a different image. The higher the resolution the more small deviations are seen. So the logic must be: The closer the dpi when saving is to the original (~72-100) the more likely the two images are the same.

Comment: How many datapoints are in your matrix? Do you know those contiguous blocks are actually contiguous? My guess is that there are white strips that are actual data that are occluded at lower DPIs.

Comment: The matrix has a shape of (1, 1654). Probably, if want to produce a raster version of the plot, I should make my own plot function that merges contigous blocks.

Comment: @Gorayni I think you missed the point of my question. You're assuming the white stripes are a rendering artifact. I am proposing that they are actually in the data.

Comment: Yes, they are not rendering artifacts.